# Check if a numbers sequence is increasing

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am in this situation: in column A I have a series of keywords, in the other columns I have a date as the header, and each date for each keyword corresponds to a value.
how do I find the keywords growing and falling?
I have already tried doing some averages between the various numbers, but the result obtained is incorrect.
Do any of you have an adequate solution?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/135EiGZsfo7YJU3hCTnsxtYRGq-aiyQyHU-D9dWTcAnU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: whats the expected output?

Comment: a positive number or a negative number

Comment: Please **show** your expected output, do you want **a** positive or negative number? Just 1? Given the example spreadsheet you linked, can you show examples of output?

Comment: What do you mean by `how do I find the keywords growing and falling?`?

Comment: I don't know exactly how the output should be, what I am interested in is knowing if the keyword is growing or falling, the dates refer to the last 5 years, has a similar problem already occurred for you? thanks

Comment: Yes, "growing and falling" isn't clear.  Do you mean for each keyword, you want to know whether it's value over time has gradually increased or decreased?  "keywords1" started at a value of 48 in 12/07/2015.  It is now at 69, in 21/06/2020.  Is the increase of 21 what you want (probably not)?  Or some form of average?  Or something else?

Comment: exactly, the result should be for each keyword, so after I group the keywords between winners and losers. exactly I would like an average, a sort of trend line, but in numbers.

Comment: Please make your sample sheet editable by everyone.  We also need a clearer example of your desired result.  What criteria are used to group keywords as losers or winners? 
 Is this what you want to be done by formulas?  Give us an example for one or more keywords, to show us what numbers you expect to see.